# What is "Fast bluetooth connection" on my Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, bluetooth

Could anyone give an explanation of the option called "Fast Bluetooth Connections" on CyanogenMod7? I don't seem to notice anything after selecting that option though.

[image: Fast bluetooth connections]

What does it possibly do?

Comment: Just as a guess it could mean that the phone tries to use Bluetooth v3 if it supports it rather than the more common v2? -edit- Actually as a better guess perhaps it means that the phone won't try and use the 'Simple Secure Pairing' that was brought in with Bluetooth v2 where the user has to type in/check a number to confirm the connection.